# how to handle with race condition with redux

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

I am using redux-effects-fetch,redux-effect-bind

```js
//my-container.ts
import {NgRedux} from 'ng2-redux';
export class MyContainer {

  private ngReduxL: any;

  constructor(ngRedux: NgRedux<any>) {
    ngRedux.provideStore(store);
    this.ngReduxL = ngRedux;
  }

mySearchMethod() {
 this.ngReduxL.dispatch(Actions.getList(searchParams));
}
}

//Action.ts
export getList(searchParams){
  return [
    showSpinnerAction('spinnerName'),
    bind(
    effectFetch(
    convertoSearchUrl,
    {method: 'GET'.....}
    ), (response) => {
     return [{
     type: 'SET_SEARCH_LIST_DATA',
     paylaod: response
     }]
    })
  ]
}
```

whenever there is change to any input value it dispatches the getList action as you can see in above code. When user hits reset the request takes too long and after that user enters some search param which takes less than the previous request.

`REQ1 ===>>>
 REQ2 ===>>>
 REQ3 ===>>>`

but when response comes back it can be in any order like

`REQ3 ===>>>
 REQ1 ===>>>
 REQ2 ===>>>`

and ultimately my list gets overwritten by last returned call.
How can i prevent so that i always have data for last request like REQ3
and other 2 should be ignored.

`REQ3 ===>>> success
 REQ1, REQ2 ===>>> cancelled/ignored`

I know with rxjs its quite easy how can do something like switchMap here.
Thanks in advance. Let me know if need more details.

Comment: dispatch not dispacth

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you saviour will be redux sagas, specifically the takeLatest helper: [docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/UsingSagaHelpers.html)

Basically, on top of solving this issue you'll also be able to use the wonderful await yield pattern which turns async stuff into the easiest thing ever.

On the downside, it see within ng2-redux, this may take a bit of setup: [github issue](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux/issues/82)

Assuming you are using angular2+, RxJS may be a far easier choice than redux. [Docs for throttle](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/throttle.html), which is specifically what you need.

You mention the issue has to do with the user dispatching another request... Consider adding an 'isLoading' item to your state, and either disabling the search or showing a loading screen while that is true. Come to think of it, that's probably the fastest solution :)

Hope that helps!